How to ignore double quotes when parsing csv file (golang)?
There is a problem with parsing csv files in the golang language; double quotes do not remain after parsing.
I have a code (golang) for parsing a csv file:
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func processCSV(inputFile, outputFile string) {
    // open input file
    inputFilePtr, err := os.Open(inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error open input file: %v", err)
    }
    defer inputFilePtr.Close()

    // Read CSV
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(inputFilePtr)
    csvReader.Comma = ','
    // save (")
    csvReader.LazyQuotes = true
    records, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error read CSV: %v", err)
    }

    // Обработка данных
    for _, record := range records {
        for i, value := range record {
            if value == "" {
                record[i] = "None"
            }
        }
    }

    // Open output file
    outputFilePtr, err := os.Create(outputFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error create output file: %v", err)
    }
    defer outputFilePtr.Close()

    // Writing processed data to an output file
    csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(outputFilePtr)
    defer csvWriter.Flush()

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := csvWriter.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error writing to output file: %v", err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    inputFileName := "input.csv"
    outputFileName := "output.csv"
    processCSV(inputFileName, outputFileName)
}


input.csv file:
one,"two",three,four
1,"2",3,
4,,6,

How to save quotes in data.
The result of the code is this:
one, two, three, four
1,2,3,None
4,None,6,None
You need this one:
one,"two",three,four
1,"2",3,None
4,None,6,None

Go's CSV module follows RFC 4180, and your requirement violates that spec.  If you need the quotes to survive, you will need to parse it yourself.  Note that your requirement is very odd; the whole point of the quotes is that you protect characters that need quoting.

The difficulty you're encountering is because of how the encoding/csv package in Go handles rates in CSV files through default. When you read and then write a CSV file, the writer only adds quotes when it deems necessary, typically to enclose fields containing a comma, newline, or a quote itself. To ensure that fields are constantly quoted in the output document as in the input, you'll want to set the UseCRLF and QuoteAll fields at the csv.Writer.
func processCSV(inputFile, outputFile string) {
    // open input file
    inputFilePtr, err := os.Open(inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error open input file: %v", err)
    }
    defer inputFilePtr.Close()

    // Read CSV
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(inputFilePtr)
    csvReader.Comma = ','
    csvReader.LazyQuotes = true
    records, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error read CSV: %v", err)
    }

    // Process data
    for _, record := range records {
        for i, value := range record {
            if value == "" {
                record[i] = "None"
            }
        }
    }

    // Open output file
    outputFilePtr, err := os.Create(outputFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error create output file: %v", err)
    }
    defer outputFilePtr.Close()

    // Writing processed data to an output file
    csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(outputFilePtr)
    csvWriter.UseCRLF = true     // Use \r\n as the line terminator
    csvWriter.Comma = ','
    csvWriter.QuoteAll = true    // Quote all fields
    defer csvWriter.Flush()

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := csvWriter.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error writing to output file: %v", err)
        }
    }

}

By setting QuoteAll to true, all fields in the output CSV will be quoted, ensuring that the output matches your requirement to retain quotes around fields as in the original file.

I have csv file with line with double quote string like:
text;//*[@class="price"]/span;text
And csv Reader generate error to read csv file. Helpful was:
reader := csv.NewReader(file)
reader.LazyQuotes = true
